# Why does Ubuntu One persistently go to a `disabled` state?`

Tags: ubuntu-one

My backup tar archive is 0.5 GB. The upload rate is limited so synching to the cloud I estimate to take 3 hours.  The upload rate is difficult to change since the internet service is provided by the landlord.

Initially I expected Ubuntu One to keep the computer awake the whole 3 hours.  My `Settings > Power` was set to 5 minutes. When I left the computer unattended and returned I saw that Ubuntu One was `disabled` so I re-enabled and I changed `Settings > Power` to `Don't Suspend`.

Many hours later I returned to see that Ubuntu One was again `disabled` so I re-enabled.  It did not indicate the synch had completed and this is unexpected.  Somehow I managed to get it to report that the synch was completed, perhaps by closing the application and re-opening it.

How do I stop this application from going to a `disabled` state?

Answer (score 1):

This may be [bug #995146](https://launchpad.net/bugs/995146).

That would mean the "disabled" status is wrong.